# Cleaning Up Matted Down Foliage In Tight Space

Tags: cleaning

This is my bulkhead area after the winter. I didn't really get a chance to get in there and clean out all the leaves before the snow came in, so I'm stuck with all the compressed dead leaves and debris you can see in the picture below. I eventually want to fill this area with small stone or something, but that's a project for another day.

This area's too tight for me to get in with a rake and a leafblower would be completely ineffective since a lot of the debris is so wet and stuck down.

Suggestions for how to clean this mess?

[image: bulkhead area]

Comment: get a smaller rake.

Comment: Yup - they make teeny tiny rakes. Get one. A hoe will also work. Or put on gloves and use your hands.

Comment: How did your cleanup project go? If you haven't already found something, I have the brand name on the rake I mentioned. It actually has two tines on the rake side, not three. My most recent use for it was to clean oak leaf guck out of rain gutters. It was kinda crude, but mostly effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "stirrup hoe" or one of the ones with a very narrow blade tapering to a point could work.

I've got a tool that I generally call my "grub hoe" because it looks somewhat like the ones used by forest fire crews. It has a narrow hoe blade on one side, almost like an adze (except I wouldn't use it for shaping logs), and a three-tine rake on the other side.

It's kinda handy. I can look for a brand name on it, if you want to know more.